# How do I enrich a Serilog log entry during ASP.NET Core middleware exception unwinding?

Tags: asp.net-core, serilog

I want to log details from HTTP requests with any unhandled exceptions using Serilog (such as the full request path, all HTTP headers, any form fields, etc). So I followed this tutorial to add information from the current `HttpContext.Request` to a logged Serilog log: https://blog.getseq.net/smart-logging-middleware-for-asp-net-core/

Here is my version of `SerilogMiddleware`;

```
/// <summary>This class logs Request Headers of any failed request.</summary>
public class SerilogMiddleware
{
    private static readonly ILogger _log = global::Serilog.Log.ForContext<SerilogMiddleware>();

    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public SerilogMiddleware( RequestDelegate next )
    {
        this.next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( next ) );
    }

    public async Task Invoke( HttpContext httpContext )
    {
        if( httpContext == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( httpContext ) );

        try
        {
            await this.next( httpContext );

            // TODO: Log certian HTTP 4xx responses?

            if( httpContext.Response?.StatusCode >= 500 )
            {
                GetLogForErrorContext( httpContext ).Warning( _MessageTemplateForHttp500 );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception ex ) when( LogException( httpContext, ex ) )
        {
            // LogException returns false, so this catch block will never be entered.
        }
    }

    const String _MessageTemplateForException = "Unhandled exception in {RequestResource}";
    const String _MessageTemplateForHttp500   = "Handled HTTP 500 in {RequestResource}";

    private static Boolean LogException( HttpContext httpContext, Exception ex )
    {
        GetLogForErrorContext( httpContext ).Error( ex, _MessageTemplateForException );

        return false; // return false so the exception is not caught and continues to propagate upwards. (I understand this is cheaper than `throw;` inside catch).
    }

    private static ILogger GetLogForErrorContext( HttpContext httpContext )
    {
        HttpRequest req = httpContext.Request;

        String resource = "{0} {1}{2} {3}".FormatInvariant( req.Method, req.Path, req.QueryString.ToString(), req.Protocol );

        // re: `ForContext`: https://nblumhardt.com/2016/08/context-and-correlation-structured-logging-concepts-in-net-5/

        ILogger result = _log
            .ForContext( "RequestHeaders" , req.Headers.ToDictionary( h => h.Key, h => h.Value.ToString() /* Returns all values, comma-separated */ ), destructureObjects: true )
            .ForContext( "RequestResource", resource )
            .ForContext( "ResponseStatus", httpContext.Response?.StatusCode )
        ;

        if( req.HasFormContentType )
            result = result.ForContext( "RequestForm", req.Form.ToDictionary( v => v.Key, v => v.Value.ToString() ) );

        return result;
    }
}
```

However, I also have Serilog in my `IWebHostBuilder` code:

```
IWebHostBuilder webHostBuilder = WebHost
    .CreateDefaultBuilder( args )
    .ConfigureLogging( (ctx, cfg ) =>
    {
        cfg.ClearProviders();
        cfg.AddSerilog(); // it's unclear if this is required or not
    } )
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseSerilog();

webHostBuilder.Build().Run();
```

In short:

- This is an ASP.NET Core middleware class that wraps `await next( context )` in a `try/catch` that get an `ILogger` using `Log.ForContext( ... )` to add new properties to the logger (e.g. request path, response code, etc).
- Because this code actually invokes `ILogger.Error` it causes the event to be logged immediately.
- But the `try/catch` lets the exception continue to propagate up the call-stack (by using `catch( Exception ex ) when ( LogExceptionThenReturnFalse( httpContext, ex ) )`.
- ...which means Serilog logs the exception and HTTP request again using default enrichment.

I want Serilog to only log the exception once, with my added enrichment. The quick-fix would be to fully catch the exception in my `SerilogMiddleware` to prevent further propagation, but that means it doesn't hit the Serilog `ILogger` configured in my `IWebHostBuilder`. And if I let the exception propagate and don't log it in my middleware then I can't log data from `HttpContext`.

How do I "attach" information to the current Serilog "context" so that when the exception is eventually caught and logged by the `IWebHostBuilder` Serilog logger it includes additional `HttpContext` data?

Comment: `ConfigureLogging()` isn't required in conjunction with `UseSerilog()` - HTH

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt Have you figured out why I'm not a fan of Fluent APIs using Extension Methods yet? :D

Comment: I have this exact problem, no solution yet?

Comment: @sianabanana No, sorry :( My application still has duplicate events logged because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution i have found so far, and is clearly a hack,
Idea stolen from here - https://blog.datalust.co/smart-logging-middleware-for-asp-net-core/

Add a middleware class to capture the exception and add manually.

```
// Idea from https://blog.datalust.co/smart-logging-middleware-for-asp-net-core/
public class LogDetailsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    private readonly IUserManager _userManager;

    private readonly ILogger _logger = Serilog.Log.ForContext<LogDetailsMiddleware>();

    public LogDetailsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IUserManager userManager)
    {
        if (next == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
        }

        _next = next;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));
        }

        LogContext.PushProperty("Email", _userManager.CurrentUser.Email);
        LogContext.PushProperty("Url", _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl());

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        try
        {
        await _next(httpContext);
            sw.Stop();
        }
        // Never caught, because `LogException()` returns false.
        catch (Exception ex) when (LogException( sw, ex)) { }
    }

    bool LogException(Stopwatch sw, Exception ex)
    {
        sw.Stop();
        
        _logger.Error(ex, "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.");

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

We are logging our requests with `HttpClientFactory`

```
services.AddHttpClient("clientWithLogger")
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<HttpClientLoggingHandler>();
```

And our `HttpClientLoggingHandler`

```
public class HttpClientLoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<HttpClientLoggingHandler> _logger;

    public HttpClientLoggingHandler(ILogger<HttpClientLoggingHandler> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        _logger.LogInformation("Starting request to '{requestUri}'", request.RequestUri);
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        sw.Stop();
        _logger.LogInformation("Finished request to '{requestUri}' in {elapsedMilliseconds}ms, response: {response}",
            request.RequestUri, sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        return response;
    }
}
```

Then we can simply use HttpClientFactory

```
public class DeviceDetector
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
    private const string LicenceKey = "XXX";
    private const string Domain = "https://xxx/api/v1/";

    public DeviceDetector(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<Device> DetectDevice(string userAgent)
    {
        var url = $"{Domain}{LicenceKey}";
        var result = await _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("clientWithLogger").GetStringAsync(url);
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Device>(result);
    }
}
```

This way we use the normal ILogger, which is Serilog behind the scenes, and have total control over what is logging and when.

**Edit**

If you just want to log the errors then the logic can be easily added

```
public class HttpClientLoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ILogger<HttpClientLoggingHandler> _logger;

    public HttpClientLoggingHandler(ILogger<HttpClientLoggingHandler> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Log error requests
        try
        {
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Success status code
            }
            else if( (int)response.StatusCode >= 500 )
            {
                // error 500
            }
        }
        catch( Exception ex ) when( LogException( httpContext, ex ) )
        {
            // LogException returns false, so this catch block will never be entered.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not interested in logging all requests. I just want to log properties of the request in the event of an exception without causing duplicate log entries.

Comment: While it is not exactly the question, i think it provides a good approximation to control the log of the requests